# How to enable this Visual Studio Code vertical line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

**This line appears when typing**.

Screenshot of the image from an online video below.

[image]

Comment: This shows new lines of code added to your previous version of the file. Are you using any version management in your application?

Comment: @Arihant No, I'm not using any version management

Comment: In the online video, the instructor is using version management tool like `Github` or `Bitbucket` to manage different versions of his code. Hence VS code, highlights `green color for any line addition` , `yellow for line update/edit` and `red arrow for line deletion`. Please research on this, it will be useful.

Comment: @Arihant thanks for the info and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are referred to as "diff decorations". You can control them by opening up your [settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) and searching for "diffDecorations".

You'll want to verify that `scm.diffDecorations` is set to either `all` or `gutter`. Additionally, as mentioned in the comments, you'll need to be using an SCM tool.